# c get the return value of thread function & UI thread stucked

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, waitforsingleobject

I wanted to use a thread to do something that could not return immediately when i click a button called **button1**
here is my code :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hWndDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        //do something.......

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
            {
                HANDLE thread1;
                DWORD exitCode;
                DWORD thread1ID;
                thread1 =  CreateThread(NULL,0,threadProc,(LPVOID)2,0,&thread1ID );
                WaitForSingleObject(thread1,INFINITE);
                GetExitCodeThread(thread1,&exitCode);

            }
            return TRUE;

        }
        return TRUE;
    //other code..................
    }
    //return DefWindowProc (hWndDlg, Msg, wParam, lParam) ;
    return FALSE;
}
```

`thread1` prototype:

```
DWORD WINAPI thread1(LPVOID n)
{
    Sleep((DWORD)n*1000*2);
    return (DWORD)n * 10;
}
```

After I click button1 (ID:IDC_BUTTON1),UI thread was stucked for about the amount of how long `Sleep` did.
if I don't use `WaitForSingleObject` , `exitCode` always return 259(STILL_ALIVE)?

How can I do to get the return value of `thread1` and UI thread couldn't be stucked ?

**EDIT**

using `PostThreadMessage` :

```
case IDC_BUTTON1:
    {
        HANDLE thread1;
        DWORD exitCode;
        DWORD thread1ID;
        DWORD mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        thread1 =  CreateThread(NULL,0,threadProc,(LPVOID)mainThreadId,0,&thread1ID );

    }
    return TRUE;
```

and a new Message in `DlgProc`:

```
case WM_FINISHED_FETCH:
    MessageBox(NULL,NULL,NULL,MB_OK);
    return TRUE;
```

`mainThreadId` is the ui thread id.

in `threadProc`

```
PostThreadMessage((DWORD)mainThreadId,WM_FINISHED_FETCH,0,0);
```

code under `WM_FINISHED_FETCH` never trigger.

Comment: re update: PostThreadMessage is a bad idea. That needs processing inside your main message loop since it is posted without a target window handle. You should be calling PostMessage and passing the window handle of the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats the point in creating a thread if you are going to block the ui thread to wait for it? If you need to do something on the ui thread once your other thread finishes, consider posting a private message to the ui thread. See `PostThreadMessage`.

Comment: I know creating a threading that block the ui thread is useless. so I'm trying to prevent that happens. I just want to get return value of `thread1` as soon as it finished and send it to main thread, so I can use `exitCode` to do next step. Can you please give me some sample code of that?

Comment: No sample code, research PostThreadMessage so your executing thread can tell the ui thread to do something with its result.

Comment: `PostThreadMessage` can have some weird behaviors around it.  For example if your UI code happens to be inside a modal dialog that has its own message pump (say, like `MessageBox` does), you might not get to process the message.  Using `PostMessage` on an hwnd (even an invisible hwnd for message-only purposes) is more reliable.